# How to access custom REST controller in managed package via Site

Tags: apex, managed-package, site.com, restresource

I had a custom Apex REST controller which was made available by a `Site`

> https://xxx.umx.force.com/site-name/services/apexrest/urlMapping

But now I've added the Apex class into a managed package, I cannot access the REST controller anymore?

How do I access the REST endpoint?

Comment: P.S. I realized I linked the wrong duplicate. See my additional link.

Comment: @sfdcfox - fair enough... mine is obviously a duplicate. It took much more Googling than usual to find the answer I was looking for, so I thought I would add a question... I must have been searching for the wrong things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to add the managed package namespace into the URL

> https://xxx.umx.force.com/site-name/services/apexrest/namespace/urlMapping